# Am I obliged to use SSH in order to open a terminal towards my Vagrant VM?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

Am I obliged to use SSH in order to open a terminal towards my Vagrant VM?

Is there any other way?

Comment: What's wrong with SSH and what do you want instead? I'm asking this because this question would be far more practical if asked as "How to connect to a Vagrant VM through <...>?" It likely depends on a box used though...

Comment: I dont know, it just feels weird to have multiple SSH tabs open - that's my use case, I got a node.js server which blocks my terminal when I run it, and then I gotta open a new terminal and re-SSH to the VM. I guess it's not a problem but I'm wondering if I can launch some remote console or something

Comment: You can have multiple tabs in control of one SSH session, look at `screen`, `tmux` and `byobu`. I use `byobu` myself.

Comment: You can do anything you like with your VM. It's a normal virtual machine running, so you can telnet it, run it with a gui or do whatever you do on other servers. I personally stick to ssh with `tmux`, having two or three ssh connections to my box open beside each other.

Comment: just to specify my HOST os is OSX and my VM is a headless VM (no Gui)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable GUI for your VM.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

Comment: wouldn't that complicate things / make the VM heavier, slower?